# Latency on Azure SQL Server vs. Fabric Datawarehouse SQL Server

Tags: azure, system.data, microsoft-fabric

Azure SQL Server vs. Fabric Datawarehouse SQL Server

I'm in the process of moving an application's data source from Azure SQL Server to a Fabric Datawarehouse.
However, it seems like latency is a huge difference on those two platforms.

I have written a small test program to run some testing. Basically, it just takes 1000 round trips to the server executing a small T-SQL statement and logs the time used.

My Azure SQL Server is located in "West Europe," while my Fabric Datawarehouse SQL Server is located in "North Europe."

I have two Azure VMs, one located in "West Europe" and the other located in "North Europe."

**Running from a client in West Europe:**

Azure SQL Server = 2 seconds

Fabric SQL Server = 27 seconds

**Running from a client in North Europe:**

Azure SQL Server = 17 seconds

*Fabric SQL Server = 17 seconds*

So, everything is as expected (it is vital where the client program resides in terms of latency), except that Fabric querying takes 17 seconds even when my test program runs from a VM located in the same area as the Fabric Datawarehouse (North Europe in this case).

The SQL itself: "SELECT 'Hello World'" should not take more than a nanosecond (or two) to execute on both, so the difference has to be latency.
And I really don't understand why the difference should be that big.
Is there something that can be adjusted on the Fabric side? Anyone?

My testprogram is quite simple

```
    Dim CurrConnection = New SqlConnection(SQL_CONNECTION_STRING)
    With CurrConnection
        .Open()
        Dim SCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        With SCommand
            .Connection = CurrConnection
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------CONNECTING TO SQL RUNNING 1000 HOOPS --------------------------------------------------------")
            Debug.Print(Now().ToString)
            Console.WriteLine(Now().ToString)

            For i = 1 To 1000
                .CommandText = "SELECT 'Hello World From SQL SERVER'"
                Dim p As Object = .ExecuteScalar()
                If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine(i & " -  " & p.ToString)
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .Close()
    End With
    Console.WriteLine(Now().ToString)
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------FINSH CONNECTING TO SQL RUNNING 1000 CALL--------------------------------------------------------")
```

Tnx
perove

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL server is built for OLTP workload, so it will run better for multiple small queries. Fabrick Wharehouse is built for OLAP workload and will be a better suite for a smaller number of queries each aggregating a large amount of data.

If your application is meant to run many small queries, each reading or updating just a few table rows, you should stick with the Azure SQL server.